# Sticky siderbar in React across the components

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to create a sticky sidebar that moves across certain components. The CSS' sticky property allows me (AFAIK) to move only within the component it was created in, so my question is - what's the best solution to have the sticky sidebar only across certain components? Fixed position sets for everything and I need it only for across 3-4 components.

```
 export default function Home() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Navbar />
                <LandingPage />
{* from here sticky sidebar *}
                <About />
                <Products />
{* to this point }
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Sidebar component that contains the  About and Product components. Then use it the same way you're using the Navbar and LandingPage component.

```
export default function Sidebar(){
  return (
    <div className='sidebar'>
      <About />
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
};
```

then

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Navbar />
      <LandingPage />
      <Sidebar />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```